# Power BI report to show inventory values on hand

Tags: sql-server, powerbi

this one has been stumping me for quite some time.  I'm looking to find the best approach to generate a - currently on hand per patient report.

Ideally I'd like to be able to show the last 30 days of inventory.

The schema is currently something similar to this below.  Currently the table only stores one type of product, but I'll eventually add a productId to this.  As it stands, each entry is a unique instance.  I'm looking to sum the number of bottles, and the volume, per patient, per day.

```
[BottleId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PatientId] [int] NOT NULL,
[VolumeInMl] [float] NOT NULL,  --volume of the bottle
[CreatedDT] [datetime] NOT NULL,  -- This is when the item came into inventory
[PickedForDate] [date] NULL -- this is the date the bottle left inventory
```

I figure I'll have to transform this to another representation, but I'm looking for advice on what that may be, and if I can do it entirely in the PowerBI service, or need to process this further on the SQL Server side.  My preference would be to offload that transformation to PBI.

It's farily simple to come up with today's inventory.  I just sum up bottles by PatientId where PickedForDate is null.  When doing it historically, I find it much more complex.

Edited:
@siggemannen had a great point to add what my desired output is.

For historical levels I'm looking to be able to graph daily or monthly values for the patient.  So I figure it'd be best to have data like:

| patientID | Date | volumeInStock |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jan/1/2020 | 1234 |
| 2 | Jan/1/2020 | 55 |
| 1 | Jan/2/2020 | 1000 |
| 2 | Jan/2/2020 | 341 |
| 3 | Jan/3/2020 | 15 |

---

Update:
I think I may have found an avenue to transform this data to a more reportable format.  I figured that if I could get one row for every day that an item is in stock, then I can sum/count grouped by PatientId and Date.

This post helped me immensely (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Create-rows-for-every-date-in-date-range/m-p/733811/highlight/true#M353977).

It says to create a custom column with all the dates between certain dates, then expand that column to new rows.

This is the formula to add the new column.
=List.Dates([From], Number.From([Till]-[From])+1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))

I've been working down this road, and it definitely seems to be a solution for me.

Comment: Could you explain what historical inventory would mean in this case? It might help to post some example data and expected output

Comment: Could you make it a a bit more readable? Check out markdown tables on stackoverflow

Comment: @siggemannen thank you for the tip.  That's done now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited the post above but answering this here too.

I think I may have found an avenue to transform this data to a more reportable format. I figured that if I could get one row for every day that an item is in stock, then I can sum/count grouped by PatientId and Date.

This post helped me immensely (https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Create-rows-for-every-date-in-date-range/m-p/733811/highlight/true#M353977).

It says to create a custom column with all the dates between certain dates, then expand that column to new rows.

This is the formula to add the new column. =List.Dates([From], Number.From([Till]-[From])+1, #duration(1, 0, 0, 0))

I've been working down this road, and it definitely seems to be a solution for me.